# Convert SQL to LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I am unable to write the below mentioned query into Linq.

```sql
SELECT  
  dateentered,  
  sum(Advance) AS amount,  
  CAST(100 * sum(sum(Advance)) OVER (ORDER BY dateentered) 
     / sum(sum(Advance)) OVER () AS numeric(10, 2)) AS percentage 
FROM Portfolio WHERE [Date Funded]>='12/1/2015' and [Date Funded]<='11/30/2020' 
GROUP BY dateentered
```

I am able to execute in SQL but unable to convert into linq. More I used linqer to convert but it also not working.

Comment: Have you ever tried typing this query in linq? If you have tried, share it with us, where did you have problems, exactly what part you cannot do.

Comment: this looks like a tough one to help (although it might be easy if we were you).

Comment: Not everything in SQL has a LINQ equivalent. This is an example.

Comment: More often than not it's better to just use raw SQL than try to trick LINQ into building that exact query.

Comment: You have perfectly fine SQL. EF Core has APIs to execute such SQL. No translation is necessary or even desirable. Sometimes, the right answer to "how?" is simply: "don't"

Comment: If you could add some example data (add Portfolio table data and the sql command execute result), might be it is easier for us to reproduce the problem and help you.

Answer (score -4):

SQL language is limited and often you have to use kludges get required results.  c# is a much more robust language. Here is my model of the query

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context db = new Context();

            var results = db.Portfolio.Where(x => (x.Date_Funded.Date >= DateTime.Parse("12/1/2015")) && (x.Date_Funded.Date <= DateTime.Parse("11/39/2020")))
                .OrderBy(x => x.dateentered)
                .GroupBy(x => x.dateentered.Date)
                .Select(x => new { dateentered = x.Key, sum = x.Sum(y => y.Advance) })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    dateentered = x.dateentered,
                    amount = x.sum,
                    percentage = Math.Round((100 * x.sum), 2)
                }).ToList();

            
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<Portfolio> Portfolio { get; set; }
    }
    public class Portfolio
    {
        public DateTime dateentered { get; set; }
        public decimal Advance { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date_Funded { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the `OVER` window function

Comment: @Charlieface : The original also does do anything with the OVER.  The original SQL I don't think is actually working the way the OP wants it to.  I just translated the original SQL the best I could.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("12/1/2015")` As a general rule I'd encourage using the `DateTime` constructor (or use `ParseExact`), as well as move that logic _outside_ of the LINQ query (i.e. put it earlier).

Comment: Not sure you're right He's got `100 *        sum(    sum(Advance)    ) OVER (ORDER BY dateentered) 
     / sum(     sum(Advance)     ) OVER ()` which if I'm not mistaken will give the running percentage of `sum(advance)`

Comment: @Charlieface : Over does nothing when you are already grouped by the dateentered.  Looks like the SQL is trying to round to 2 percentage points.  So  I think a simple conversion to integer will work : (int)(100 * x.sum)

Comment: Good point, missed that. Wonder if he's got the wrong grouping

Comment: @Charlieface : I thought a parenthesis in the wrong location.

Comment: *SQL language is limited* -- Why? It's very expressive. What requires an entire block of imperative C# code it does in one declarative statement. OP shouldn't even want to "convert" it into LINQ. The SQL statement, by the way, is correct, while your code isn't.

Comment: @GertArnold : SQL sometimes take 10 instruction to do the same as you can do in c# in one instruction.